# How to change look and feel of force.com sites?

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites

I have followed steps suggested in below url
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/customizing-the-look-and-feel-of-your-force-com-site.

still look and feel of my force.com site is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different causes depending on what you have done.

- It could be that the static resource is not set up correctly.  Use the chrome developer tools console to check if the image resource is being loaded or if the path it is loading is incorrect.
- It could be a caching issue with your page. You can set cache attributes on the [apex:page](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) element.
- It could be that you are actually describing  [this problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/9164/154.), which is that you are trying to change the App (collection of tabs) logo.  You cannot change the logo of *that* App:
  [image: Force.com Site's Internal Salesforce App logo]