# How can I change the logo on a public site?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, force.com-sites, site.com, customization

I spend a fair amount of time trying to update the logo for my public site.  However, I was trying to edit the sitetemplate with no avail and the header.svc

Do I put this in Static resources or documents or elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the this [tutorial](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/customizing-the-look-and-feel-of-your-force-com-site)

> Modify the SiteHeader to display your company's logo (Logo) and use your company's stylesheet:

Click Setup | Develop | Components.

Click Edit next to the SiteHeader component.

Replace the following line:

```
<apex:image url="{!$Site.Prefix}{!$Label.site.img_path}/force_logo.gif"style="align: left;" alt="Salesforce"
  width="233" height="55" title="Salesforce"/>
```

with this new line:

```
 <apex:image id="logo" value="{!$Resource.Logo}"/>
```

The image or logo needs to be in static resource file .

If you want to change the logo in sfdc application refer this earlier [answered question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/how-to-change-the-logo-in-force-com-sites)

Comment: I followed that tutorial and it's still there.  I have my static resource set to public, I named it logo, I modified the header component with the apex:image tag.  For some reason it's still not showing up.

Comment: Can you share screenshot? I guess you will need to create a custom sfdc app and assign a different logo and then configure that for guest user

Comment: I think what is happening is my visualforce page is not using the site template.  When I preview the site template by itself the logo is there.  How can I use the site template on that visualforce page?

Comment: you have to say header=false in vf .whats your home page of site ? Configure Home page as your vf page

Comment: Active Site Home Page = vfDHS_Survey1

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Survey__c" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:form > 
     <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="true" title="Feedback on State Health Assessment - Page 1">

Comment: ccan you make showheader = false

Comment: I did.  under the apex:page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37580/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-tjcinnamon).

Comment: this is what was needed.  Thanks @mohith.

<apex:page standardController="Survey__c" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:composition template="SiteTemplate">
         <apex:define name="body">