# How to change site.com logo?

Tags: force.com-sites

I am trying to change the upper left logo for a site.com vf page. I already looked at this answer [How to change the Logo in Force.com sites?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/how-to-change-the-logo-in-force-com-sites)

What I tried below won't work. I would like to keep the header and just change the logo (if possible).

If not, I need to understand what I need to do instead.

What I did in my site.com page header so far is to replace `<apex:image url="{!$Site.Prefix}/img/sites/force_logo.png" style="align: left;" alt="Salesforce" width="233" height="55" title="Salesforce"/>` with this code `<apex:image id="logo" value="{!$Resource.ChooseSeminarVFPageIcon}"/>` where the latter is a .png file but it hasn't helped.

Comment: I think `{! URLFOR($Resource.ChooseSeminarVFPageIcon) }` will add the necessary site prefix to the URL.

Comment: To to be certain, this is what I changed it to per your suggestion. It still shows me the SF '16 butterfly icon   <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.ChooseSeminarVFPageIcon)}" style="align: left;" alt="Salesforce" width="233" height="55" title="Salesforce"/>

Comment: Sounds like you are seeing what the accepted answer to the question you link to explains.